# how to convert to date an attribute already converted by Javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i'm doing an entry control to my dates entred by the user 
my view code works very well but when it goes to the controller it can't convert the attributes to date !!!
This is my controller method :

```html
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
        {
            Projet projet = new Projet();
            int x=Convert.ToInt32(TempData.Peek("x").ToString());
            projet.UtilisateurID = x;
            string name = form["nom"].ToString();
            var n = (from p in db.Projets
                     where (p.nomP.Equals(name))
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();
            if (n != null)
                ViewBag.NomExiste = "Ce Nom De Projet Existe Déjà!";
            else
            {
                projet.nomP = form["nom"];
                if (form["DateDebut"].Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    projet.DateDebut = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateDebut"]);
                };
                if (form["DateFinPrevue"].Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    projet.DateFinPrevue = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateFinPrevue"]);
                };
                projet.DateFinReele = null;
                if (form["DateFinReele"].Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    projet.DateFinReele = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateFinReele"]);
                };
                projet.Description = form["Description"];
                projet.etat = form["etat"];
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Projets.Add(projet);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                };
            };
            return View(projet);
        }
```

This is a part of my view :

```html
<!--Date Debut !!-->
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                                         <label class="cke_label" for="DateDebut">Date Debut</label>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                                         <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                                             <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                                                 <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" required="" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateDebut must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ Date Debut est requis." id="DateDebut" name="DateDebut" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" data-type="date" aria-owns="DateDebut_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                                                 <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateDebut_dateview">
                                                                     <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                                                     <span data-for='DateDebut' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
                                                                 </span>
                                                             </span>
                                                         </span>
                                                         <script>
                                                     jQuery(function () {
                                                         jQuery("#DateDebut").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1940, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2100, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                                     });
                                                         </script>
                                                         <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateDebut" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
                                                 <br /><br />
                                                 <!--Date fin Prevue !!-->
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                                         <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinPrevue">Date Fin Prevue</label>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                                         <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                                             <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                                                 <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" required="" style="width: 100%;" data-greaterdate-field="DateDebut" data-greaterdate-msg='la Date Fin prévue doit être inférieure à la date début du projet ! ' data-val-date="The field DateFinPrevue must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinPrevue est requis." id="DateFinPrevue" name="DateFinPrevue" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinPrevue_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                                                 <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinPrevue_dateview">
                                                                     <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                                                     <span data-for='DateFinPrevue' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
                                                                 </span>
                                                             </span>
                                                         </span>
                                                         <script>
                                                     jQuery(function () {
                                                         jQuery("#DateFinPrevue").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1940, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2100, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                                     });
                                                         </script>
                                                         <span class="text" required="" data-valmsg-for="DateFinPrevue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
                                                 <br /><br />
                                                 <!--Date fin Reele !!-->
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                                         <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinReele">Date Fin Reele</label>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                                         <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                                             <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                                                 <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-greaterdate-field="DateDebut" data-greaterdate-msg='la Date Fin Réelle doit être inférieure à la date début du projet ! ' data-val-date="The field DateFinReele must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinReele est requis." id="DateFinReele" name="DateFinReele" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" data-type="date" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinReele_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                                                 <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinReele_dateview">
                                                                     <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                                                     <span data-for='DateFinReele' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
                                                                 </span>
                                                             </span>
                                                         </span>
                                                         <script>
                                                     jQuery(function () {
                                                         jQuery("#DateFinReele").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1940, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2100, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                                     });
                                                         </script>
                                                         <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinReele" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <script>
                                                 $(document).ready(function () {
                                                     function DateDebutChange() {
                                                         var DateDebutDate = DateDebut.value(),
                                                             DateFinPrevueDate = DateFinPrevue.value();
                                                         if (DateDebutDate) {
                                                             DateDebutDate = new Date(DateDebutDate);
                                                             DateDebutDate.setDate(DateDebutDate.getDate());
                                                             DateFinPrevue.min(DateDebutDate);
                                                         } else if (DateFinPrevueDate) {
                                                             DateDebut.max(new Date(DateFinPrevueDate));
                                                         } else {
                                                             DateFinPrevueDate = new Date();
                                                             DateDebut.max(DateFinPrevueDate);
                                                             DateFinPrevue.min(DateFinPrevueDate);
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                     function DateFinPrevueChange() {
                                                         var DateFinPrevueDate = DateFinPrevue.value(),
                                                             DateDebutDate = DateDebut.value();
                                                         if (DateFinPrevueDate) {
                                                             DateFinPrevueDate = new Date(DateFinPrevueDate);
                                                             DateFinPrevueDate.setDate(DateFinPrevueDate.getDate());
                                                             DateDebut.max(DateFinPrevueDate);
                                                         } else if (DateDebutDate) {
                                                             DateFinPrevue.min(new Date(DateDebutDate));
                                                         } else {
                                                             DateFinPrevueDate = new Date();
                                                             DateDebut.max(DateFinPrevueDate)
                                                             DateFinPrevue.min(DateFinPrevueDate);
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                     var DateDebut = $("#DateDebut").kendoDatePicker({
                                                         change: DateDebutChange
                                                     }).data("kendoDatePicker");
                                                     var DateFinPrevue = $("#DateFinPrevue").kendoDatePicker({
                                                         change: DateFinPrevueChange
                                                     }).data("kendoDatePicker");
                                                     DateDebut.max(DateFinPrevue.value());
                                                     DateFinPrevue.min(DateDebut.value());
                                                 });
                                             </script>
                                         </div>
```

Comment: i'm blocked and i still looking for a solution .

Comment: it shows me FormatException when i execute

Comment: @Stephen Muecke you helped me a lot ! can you help me one more time please :) ! thanks a lot !

Comment: you have two divs extra in the above code. is it all the code or you didn't post everything?

Comment: i didn't post everything

Answer (score 0):

well , my problem is solved !!! 
the problem is that the javascript default date format is not the same as the c# default date format so i did a conversion in my controller and it worked very well

This is my controller Method :

```html
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
        {
            Projet projet = new Projet();
            int x=Convert.ToInt32(TempData.Peek("x").ToString());
            projet.UtilisateurID = x;
            string name = form["nom"].ToString();
            var n = (from p in db.Projets
                     where (p.nomP.Equals(name))
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();
            if (n != null)
                ViewBag.NomExiste = "Ce Nom De Projet Existe Déjà!";
            else
            {
                projet.nomP = form["nom"];
                if (form["DateDebut"].Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    string s = form["DateDebut"];
                    DateTime DateDebut1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    projet.DateDebut = DateDebut1;
                };
                if (form["DateFinPrevue"].Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    string s = form["DateFinPrevue"];
                    DateTime DateFinPrevue1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    projet.DateFinPrevue = DateFinPrevue1;
                };
                projet.DateFinReele = null;
                if (form["DateFinReele"].Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    string s = form["DateFinReele"];
                    DateTime DateFinReele1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    projet.DateFinReele = DateFinReele1;
                };
                projet.Description = form["Description"];
                projet.etat = form["etat"];
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Projets.Add(projet);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                };
            };
            return View(projet);
        }
```

thanks anyway for your help !

Comment: but now i have another problem : i want to compare today's date with a date entred by the user !